# How to control node names when converting CSV to JSON in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm using a simple csv to json script in python and I've successfully converted CSV to JSON using this...

```
csvFilePath = ("x.csv")

# Read the CSV and add the data to a dictionary
data = {}
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        objectid = csvRow["objectid"]
        data[objectid] = csvRow
        d = csvrow

# Converts dictionary to JSON list
json_string = json.dumps([data], indent = 4)
```

The resulting JSON looks like this...

```
[
{
    "15494": {
        "status": "Open", 
        "site_name": "Healthpromed Municipality of Vieques", 
        "objectid": "15494", 
        "utilities": "No", 
        "site_dashboard_surrogate_key": "BPS-H80-019569", 
        "supplies": "No", 
        "structural": "No", 
        "staff": "No"
    }, 
    "1": {
        "status": "Closed", 
        "site_name": "PUBLIC HEALTH AND HUMAN SERVICES, MONTANA DEPARTMENT OF", 
        "objectid": "1", 
        "utilities": "No", 
        "site_dashboard_surrogate_key": "010478A2-14EF-4B7B-84A0-2618F311D82F", 
        "supplies": "No", 
        "structural": "No", 
        "staff": "No"
    }
}]
```

I need help in changing the node names (i.e. "15494", "1") which are set by the "objectid" to "attributes"

The code I want should look like this...

```
[
{
    "attributes": {
        "status": "Open", 
        "site_name": "Healthpromed Municipality of Vieques", 
        "objectid": "15494", 
        "utilities": "No", 
        "site_dashboard_surrogate_key": "BPS-H80-019569", 
        "supplies": "No", 
        "structural": "No", 
        "staff": "No"
    }, 
    "attributes": {
        "status": "Closed", 
        "site_name": "PUBLIC HEALTH AND HUMAN SERVICES, MONTANA DEPARTMENT OF", 
        "objectid": "1", 
        "utilities": "No", 
        "site_dashboard_surrogate_key": "010478A2-14EF-4B7B-84A0-2618F311D82F", 
        "supplies": "No", 
        "structural": "No", 
        "staff": "No"
    }
}]
```

Any ideas? I'm at wit ends here. I've tried to replace the objectid = csvRow["objectid"] to ["attributes"] in the for loop but it just overwrites the first entry.

Comment: Actually your expected json is not valid, it will through `Duplicate key "attributes"`

Comment: That's what the REST API I'm working with accepts( https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/apply-edits-feature-service-layer-.htm) under request parameters

Comment: Did you check the json you wanted is even a valid json format or not?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I guess this is what you need as per the **ArcGIS REST API** documentation. Hope it'll help you :)

```
csvFilePath = ("x.csv")

# Read the CSV and add the data to a dictionary
data = [] # make it a list
object = {} # initialize a dictionary
with open(csvFilePath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        object['attributes'] = csvRow["objectid"] # create dictionary
        data.append(dict(object)); # append every dictionary to list
        d = csvrow

# Converts dictionary to JSON list
json_string = json.dumps(data, indent = 4) # make json dump your list of dictionary
```